# SQL:Conditional Operator in SQL Join Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I was trying to Join two tables based on certain conditions , one of the condition is if my Column Flag contains value=1 then i use "=" operator otherwise "<>"

This is basically I want to do :

```
Select A.* from Table1 A Inner Join Table2
On A.ID Case Flag when 1 then = else <> end B.ID
```

Of course this syntax is incorrect but this is what i want to do.

Comment: yes if flag is 1 then join condition is A.ID=B.ID otherwise A.ID<>B.ID

Comment: By using "<>" what record you want to return. Explain in plain English.I think none of them will return correct records.

Comment: Yes Harsh, that's fine , this is what i want,, I want non matching records if flag is not 1 ,that is "not equal to" operator

Answer (score 3):

Just use an **OR** clause in your join:

```
Select A.* from Table1 A
Inner Join Table2
On (A.Flag = 1 AND A.ID = B.ID)
Or (A.Flag <> 1 AND A.ID <> B.ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

i prefer to not use or inside joins, so:

```
Select A.* from Table1 A 
Inner Join Table2 On  A.ID = B.ID and Flag = 1
union
Select A.* from Table1 A 
Inner Join Table2 On  A.ID <> B.ID and Flag <> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

My Style:

```
    Select A.* 
    from Table1 A 
   Inner Join Table2 On case when Flag=1 then Convert(bit,1) else  Convert(bit,0) end = 
   case when (A=B) then Convert(bit,1) else Convert(bit,0) end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost certain that your description is not what you really want.

I think you really want a flag that, when `1`, returns rows in `Table1` that are in `Table2`; and when `0`, returns rows in `Table1` that are not in `Table2`.

One explicit method uses `exists`/`not exists`:

```
Select a.*
from Table1 a
where (flag = 1 and
       exists (select 1 from Table2 b where b.id = a.id)
      ) or
      (flag <> 1 and 
       not exists (select 1 from Table2 b where b.id = a.id)
      );
```

That is, when `flag = 1` then get the rows in `Table1` whose ids are in `Table2`.  When `flag <> 1` then get the rows in `Table1` whose ids are NOT in `Table2`.

You can also implement this version of the logic using `LEFT JOIN` and `WHERE` clause:

```
Select a.*
from Table1 a left join
     Table2 b
     on a.id = b.id
where (flag = 1 and b.id is not null) or
      (flag <> 1 and b.id is null);
```